# How to create a function that would accept any collection of items that inherit a common class?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class called baseForm. It's only purpose is to be inherited, to both, give some basic functionality to its offspring and to serve as a common type for other classes to stuff those offspring into.

Then i wanted to create some handy shared functions to do various stuff with collections of these offspring, irregardless what their specific type is(since none of their specific data is required), but ran into a problem.

I have this example function

```
Public Shared Function getCommonKeys(forms As List(Of baseForm)) As keyCollection
    Dim ret As New keyCollection
    For i = 0 To forms.Count - 1
        ret.AddRange(forms(i).keys)
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

which is all well and fine until i try and do this

```
Public Class fancyForm
    Inherits baseForm
End Class

....

Dim fancyForms As List(Of fancyForm) = {New fancyForm()}.toList
Dim keys As keyCollection = baseForm.getCommonKeys(fancyForms)
```

It wont accept `List(Of fancyForm)` as `List(Of baseForm)`, even though this is fine for individual objects.

I don't want to create an explicit `baseForm` collection class because storing my stuff in those would involve a lot of casting to get to the specific data that other things need.

Is there any simple remedy to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your function in terms of `IEnumerable(Of T)` instead of `List(Of T)`, if all that you need to do is to iterate through the items:

```
Public Shared Function getCommonKeys(forms As IEnumerable(Of baseForm)) As keyCollection
```

This will now work because [`IEnumerable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is [*covariant*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) in its type parameter.

It can't work in the original form because your calling code thinks it has a `List(Of fancyForm)` - if it worked as in your original code, `getCommonKeys` would just be working with a `List(Of baseForm)` - and then what is to stop it from trying to add a new `OtherFancyForm` to that list?

This really comes down to the fact that if you have three types, `T1`, `T2` and `G(Of T)`, and `T1` and `T2` have an inheritance relationship, that doesn't, in any way, mean that `G(Of T1)` and `G(Of T2)` have that same inheritance relationship - in fact, they have no such relationships.

---

I would also change the body of your method to use more idiomatic style:

```
    Dim ret As New keyCollection
    For Each frm as baseForm in forms
        ret.AddRange(frm.keys)
    Next
    Return ret
```